# Uncheck radiofield

Tags: javascript, checkbox, extjs, radio-button, extjs6-modern

I need to click on a radiofield and check it, click another time on the same radiofield and uncheck it.

My code doesen't work because the `getChecked()` is always true!
This is my function, triggered on click event.
My extjs version is 6.2.1.167

```
listeners: {
    click: {
        element: 'element',
        fn: function (event, target) {
            var radioField = this.component;
            if (radioField.getChecked()) {
                radioField.setChecked(false);
            }
            else {
                radioField.setChecked(true);
            }
        }
    }
},
```

Comment: Why using radio and not checkbox?

Comment: @LenapCapo you are right, i know... but it not depends on me

Comment: @CristinaMoretti, there is no click event on a modern radiofield. It is a check event and will always, always return true. Even attempting to use a change event will not work because change on radiofields only trigger when another radio field is checked. You need to create a custom override to either a) introduce a custom event or b) override an existing event. Here is the documentation on the radiofield. https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/modern/Ext.field.Radio.html

Answer (score 1):

Your example works in my case.

[Sencha Fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2r2v)

But as @LenapCapo said, you are trying to use radio boxes for other purposes. If you need a round checkbox, better redefine checkbox styles.

Comment: please can you try with version 6.2.1.167 modern? it doesen't work with this version...

Comment: Yes, on 6.2.1 this does not work. I suggest you use the following solution `{
                xtype: 'checkboxfield',
                name: 'color',
                cls: 'x-radiofield',
                value: 'red',
                label: 'Red',
                checked: true
            }` https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2r49

Comment: Thanks you are the best. can you help me for the last time please? How should I do to enable just single selection? https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2r4t

Comment: Remove the property `checked` from the needed field if you mean the initial state. If you want to be able to select only one field when switching, you need the radiofield https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/6.2.1/modern/Ext.field.Radio.html

Comment: so isn't possible to select only one field and have the possibility to deselect?

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure you're checking the correct function on the radio? I've seen it be

```
radioField.checked
```

Or are you using your own method of checking the radio?

Comment: do you mean radiofield.checked instead of getChecked() ?